# Odds of correct guess in 'pick all options that are valid' multiple choice question with 4 options, where two are correct.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say that I am taking a quizz and I arrive at a  question that has four alternatives, of which two are correct, and 
I have to  select the 2 correct options  to score correctly on that question.

An example.

```
Of the four options below select the two which are animals:

    - a rock
    - a goat
    - a tree
    - a cat
```

That's fairly easy for a native English speaker to get right, but lets say the person taking the test spoke
no English. They would then be purely guessing. And in this case,  I was wondering what would be the odds they'd get the correct answer?

I came up with 1/6 for the following reasons:

ONE

There are (4 choose 2) ways of selecting an answer, out of which only one choice of two is correct.

```
(4 choose 2)  =   4 !           4 * 3 * 2 * 1       3 * 2 * 1
               ---------  =     -------------   =   --------- = 6. 
               2! * (4-2)!          2*1 * 2*1           1
```

So, out of 6 ways of choosing, we have one way that will win. So our odds of winning are 1/6.

TWO

If I calculate at the probability of selecting the correct answer as the probability of two events occuring in sequence, 
then the probability would be:

```
P(pick first answer correct out of 4 choices) * P(pick second answer correct out of remaining three choices) 


P(pick first answer correct out of 4 choices)  =   1/2

    Because there are two correct choices out of the 4 we could pick.

P(pick second answer correct out of remaining three choices)  = 1/3 

    and 1/2 * 1/3 = 1/6
```

So, both solution approaches yield the same probability. Thus, I think I have the correct answer, 
but would be very grateful if someone with more math experience than me could weigh in and 
let me know for sure.

Comment: Should we assume that anyone taking the test knows that there are exactly two correct choices for this question, if they didn't know that, the probability of success by random guess would be $\frac 1{16}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely correct. Your first method would work in any scenario with $n$ options and $k$ correct ones, though the second method is tougher because there could be involved casework.

Comment: thnx for the confirmation !    And you are in high school with that reputation?    Pretty impressive.  If you decide to pursue comp-sci, let me know if i can help you out some day (math-impaired scala programmer here).     ;^)

Comment: i actually am applying computer science to universities this fall, i would love to get in touch! what's the best mode of contact for you? i found this site a few years ago while looking for some help on probability, but i didn't contribute very much until i learned more in high school. i don't have a ton of CS experience, just an elementary java and python class, but one topic that's kind of interesting is the whole data analysis & machine learning thing.

Comment: email is chris <at> buildlackey.com -  you helped me out..I'm happy to help you such as i can.   Machine learning is where it's at. The robots will take most peoples jobs, but you will at least have a job building robot intelligence... until they realize we are no longer relevant... then we're doomed.  until then.. study math!